# Should commas be placed between characters when listing valid values for an input field

Tags: input, validation

We have an input field, into which the user must type a value but only certain characters are allowed. The allowed characters are:

- A-Z (any case)
- the numbers 0-9
- the $ character
- the minus character
- the underscore character

If a user enters invalid characters a tooltip appears which currently states:

> The ID may only contain the characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, $, -, _

Feedback from our tester states that he finds the commas confusing as he thinks that the error message states that a comma should be allowed! The developer thinks that the lack of commas in the error message makes it confusing.

Is there a standard way to display this sort of information? Can anyone advise?

Note: This is for an English website.

Comment: If it is an ID field, I am surprised that you allow the $ character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested wording: **You can only use upper case letters (A to Z), lower case letters (a to z), numbers (0 to 9), and the following characters: $ - _**

My suggestion is a bit more long-winded than the one above, but I have [avoided using passive voice](http://www.writing.utoronto.ca/advice/style-and-editing/passive-voice).

Also, given that there are some people who don't know what upper case and lower case mean, I've added examples, and used the word 'to' in order to avoid ambiguity.[image: screenshot of the number of times this question has been asked on Yahoo Answers]

I added a space between the other characters as I think that looks nicer. I kind of agree with your test guy that the commas are ambivalent, but I think it would be difficult to get objective evidence for that. You could do a quick [hallway usability test](http://wall-skills.com/2014/hallway-usability-tests/) by showing people the list and asking them what characters they think are allowed.

You might also want to read the [security considerations around passwords and usernames](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A2-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management), e.g. if someone's login fails, don't tell them whether it was their username or password that was incorrect; if they forget their password, just reset it and send them a link to reset their password.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was going to write "what about spaces" (because in my example a space character is not allowed), but this could of course be written explicitly.

Comment: If they do try to enter any spaces, you could just replace them with an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just listing the allowed characters be a bit more descriptive like this:

Only **uppercase letters**, **lowercase letters**, **numbers** or the symbols **$-_** are allowed.

Comment: So you would recommend putting the characters together with no spaces between them? Is this standard ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use same method that's used when users for long product keys or date of birth into a single input field where the a space or dash automatically appears after a certain amount of characters before the cursor moves to the next

Comment: In this situation, the field is one long string, so your suggestion is not applicable